# How can i make flexible XML data files for other websites?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I would like to know how can i give other website parsers an xml file or response based on arguments they request?
For example i have `show_data.php` file that can take range of params and then apply it to mysql query and then form valid xml 1.0 string.

So by this point i have finished with data fetching + xml formating based on request params.
Now how would i share that xml with other websites for their xml parsers?

Do i simply output my xml string in php file with appropriate headers or somehow else?

```
Example:
1)www.example.com request www.mypage.com/show_data.php?show=10
2)www.mypage.com/show_data.php send xml data back to www.example.com
```

It's really hard to explain since i have not worked with xml and stuff before. Hope it makes some sense.

Thanks.

Comment: **Exactly the same way** you are giving out different web pages. there is nothing complex or magic about XML. it's just text with tags, like HTML.

Comment: This really depends on the XML Schema you are using. In other words, what is the format of the XML? What elements are allowed where etc

Comment: @Col HTML is based on SGML though

Comment: @Gordon it's all based on plain text, dude.

Comment: @Col that's an oversimplification, but yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when example.com does the initial request, your page will process it and return the xml as the result. There's nothing special that you'll need to do.

```
$xml = "";

// process the xml (build it - do what you need to do)

// returning the xml to the requester
header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); 
echo $xml;
```

Comment: Great i was doing that already i was just wondering if i need to process it somehow special :)